# Can I report people on Steam for sending inappropriate messages?

Tags: steam

How can i report people that are aggressive to me on steam?  Someone has been sending me messages that contain offensive language.

Answer (score 1):

Xbox LIVE has this feature, but I don't believe that Steam does.

Instead of reporting them, you can block communication with them.

[image]

(Apologies to Retrosaur, I just had his chat window open still :P)

First, click the arrow next to their name (which I have highlighted with a red box), which will drop down a menu.

Click the "Block All Communication..." option, and you'll see the dialog on the right.

Once blocked, they will not be able to send you further messages, game invites, trade requests, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Go to his profile page. On the right there is an "Actions" tab with "Report Violation" on the bottom. There you have multiple options:

- User misconduct
- Offensive text
- Offensive imagery
- Suspected Cheater

I believe that "Offensive text" refers to text on his profile, but "User misconduct" might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Albate Would you then please be so kind to mark this answer as correct or maybe even upvote it? ;)